# Python supports `else` in loop. Is there a similar feature in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, loops, if-statement, break

In Python, the else block will be executed unless the loop is broke:

```
for person in people:
    if is_a_coder(person): break
# ... more code ...
else: # nobreak
    print('There is no coder.')
```

How can I do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `and`:

```
people.each do |person|
  break if is_a_coder(person)
  # more code
end and puts 'There is no coder.'
```